# HABTM based find without hard-coded SQL fragments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, find, has-and-belongs-to-many

Order habtm devices and devices habtm orders.

I need to find orders, having ALL specified devices

I'm doing following:

```
devices = Device.all :conditions => {:name => params[:devices].split(",")}
@orders = Order.all :joins => :devices, :conditions => {:devices => devices}
```

It produces following SQL:

> SELECT "orders".*
>
> FROM "orders"
>
> INNER JOIN "orders_devices" ON "orders_devices".order_id = "orders".id
>
> INNER JOIN "devices" ON "devices".id = "orders_devices".device_id
>
> WHERE ("orders"."devices" IN (110330561,530240381))  ORDER BY date DESC)

The last string of the query is incorrect, and sure, i get an error:

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: orders.devices

Why i'm getting this result ?

How can i solve the problem, without specifying SQL query fragments, like that:

```
:conditions => ['devices.id in (?)',[1,2]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe just this?

```
@orders = Order.all(:joins => :devices, :conditions => {"devices.id" => devices})
```

Comment: I wouldn't even know a different way to express it. It's readable, and I wouldn't think about it being an SQL-fragment (it says "the id of devices"). In *arel* you could do something like `Devices.arel_table[:id].in(devices)` but I doubt that this is better. In *DataMapper* your example could work, but DM has other issues.